# ¿Cómo obtener la ruta del cron que ejecuta un bash?

Tags: cron

Tengo un cron que ejectuta un bash, y este bash llama un script PHP que envía un correo por email.

Necesito modificar la hora en que se ejecuta el cron, pero no logro encontrar el cron en el servidor.

Probé con `sudo crontab -l` y el único cron que aparece es otro que corre otro proceso, ¿tal vez tenga que loguearme con otro usuario en el servidor?, ¿el cron puede estar en alguna otra carpeta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De los siguientes comandos:

```
$ sudo crontab -l
$ crontab -l
$ crontab -l -u francisco
```

El primero, te muestra los CRON jobs del usuario `root` (debido a que estás utilizando `sudo`), el segundo te muestra del usuario actual y el último del usuario `francisco` (usando el flag `-u`).

Es díficl decir en donde puedes encontrar el CRON que estás buscando pero lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es mirar la lista de los archivos CRON e ir tanteando. Por ejemplo, para ver la lista puedes hacer:

```
$ sudo ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
cesar
francisco
```

Y luego buscar los CRON jobs por usuario hasta dar con el que necesitas:

```
$ sudo cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/cesar
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.c44D9Y/crontab installed on Thu Oct 26 17:16:01 2017)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* 10 * * * ls -l
```

Estoy seguro que alguien vendrá con una idea mejor ya que puede ser tedioso si hay muchos usuarios y muchos CRON jobs por usuario.

Lo he probado usando Ubuntu 16.04.

---

### Actualización 1

Probando algunas cosas, puedes disminuir un poco el tema haciendo algo como esto:

```
$ sudo su
# cd /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
# find -type f -exec sh -c "echo 'CRON de {}' && cat {} | grep tgz"  \;
CRON de ./cesar
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
```

Simplemente estoy buscando los archivos CRON de cada usuario con un `cat` + `grep` para buscar una palabra específica. Antes estoy poniendo un `echo` para saber qué archivo es el que estás viendo.

Reemplaza la parte del `tgz` con algo relacionado a tu script PHP, tal vez des con el CRON de esta manera.

### Actualización 2

Para editar el crontab de un usuario puedes usar:

```
$ sudo crontab -u desarrollador -e
```

Usando el flag `-e` para editar el archivo.

Comment: la opcion 2 me sirvio, yo lo estaba haciendo con la opcion 1 y solo me aparecia el de root, y necesitaba el del usuario logueado.

ahora como puedo modificar la hora en que se ejecuta este cron?

`30 17 * * * ./solicitudTransfer.sh >> /home/desarrollador/vitacora_transfer.txt
`

me imagino que con un `nano` pero nose la ruta del documento..

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo mira mi última actualización

Comment: muchas gracias amigo por tu ayuda, solucionado!

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo de nada! No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que no se quede como una pregunta abierta. Saludos,